# How to add number of days to get the next date from current date without weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add some no. of days to get the future date. And weekends should not be included in this. How can I get this?

var startdate = "8-June-2012";
no. of days to add = 10;
enddate should be  "22-June-2012"

Comment: I think you're going to have to at least provide an example of what you're talking about. This question is vague and incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
   var startDate = "8-June-2012";
    startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
    var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 10, count = 0;
    while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
        endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
        if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
           //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
           count++;
        }
    }
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HaJpQ/40/)

Comment: setDate() and getDate() operate on the day of the month 1-31. There is no guarantee that this works if you are at the end of the month, because incrementing doesn't wrap around to the next month, it just goes to 32

Comment: @nbrooks: actually, it does wrap.

Comment: @thg435 oh really? well thanks, never knew that. I remember trying it in the past and not having it work, but I guess that was my fault then. Good to know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateWorkingDayNumbers(startDate, offset)
{
    var startDay = startDate.getDay();
    if ((startDay % 7) === 1)
    {
        return ((offset - (offset % 7)) / 7) + ((offset % 7 === 1) ? (1) : (0));
    }
    else if (offset < 7)
    {
        if ((startDay === 6))
            return 1 + ((offset > 0) ? (1) : (0));
        else if (startDay === 0)
            return 1 + ((offset === 6) ? (1) : (0));
    }
    else
    {
        return calculateWorkingDayNumbers(startDate, (((startDay % 7) + 1) % 7)) + calculateWorkingDayNumbers(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (((startDay % 7) + 1) % 7)), offset - (((startDay % 7) + 1) % 7));
    }
}
```

This (untested) code is very fast. You could also improve your solution by handling holidays too.